# Determine NAT Mapping Behaviour using two STUN servers

Tags: udp, webrtc, nat, turn

is it possible to determine the mapping behaviour of a NAT using two STUN servers? something like [here](https://webrtchacks.com/symmetric-nat/).

There are three types of mapping behaviour:

**Endpoint-Independent Mapping**:The NAT reuses the port mapping for subsequent packets sent from the same internal IP address and port (X:x) to any external IP address and port.  Specifically, X1′:x1′ equals X2′:x2′ for all Y.

**Address-Dependent Mapping**: The NAT reuses the port mapping for subsequent packets sent from the same internal IP address and port (X:x) to the same external IP address, regardless of the external port. Specifically, X1′:x1′ equals X2′:x2′ if and only if, Y2 equals Y1.

**Address and Port-Dependent Mapping**:The NAT reuses the port mapping for subsequent packets sent from the same internal IP address and port (X:x) to the same external IP address and port while the mapping is still active. Specifically, X1′:x1′ equals X2′:x2′ if and only if, Y2:y2 equals Y1:y1.

So in theory if you ask two different STUN servers for your public IP address and you get the same IP:port, you should have an Endpoint-Independent Mapping right? but **how do you differentiate the other two types?**

Answer (score 1):

I would try setting up two stun servers on different ports on the same host.

So you will need 3 stun servers in total: two on the same host and one on other.

If you get 3 different candidates, it must be address and port dependent mapping; 2 means address-dependent; 1 - endpoint-dependent; 0 - udp is probably blocked.

But this approach needs to be tested thoroughly, I believe there might be some browser-dependent surprises (see `esser50k` comment in the article you provided).

Comment: I'll try to find two public STUN servers with the same ip and different port to make my life easier. But thanks for the response! Yeah i've seen some problems with safari but it's more a proof of concept.

Comment: I don't think you'll find one, it's rather exotic setup. But it's easy to deploy your own, you just need a vm with public ip and https://github.com/coturn/coturn/ installed.

Must be something like:
`apt install coturn` and then run it with `turnserver -p <PORT_NUMBER> --stun-only`